# How to use a property in spring data @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I can't manage to inject a property from application.yml to a spring data @Query.

The following results in an EL1008E error:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Query("select e from MyEntity e where e.foo = :foo and e.env= ?#{env}")
    MyEntity findByFoo(@Param("foo") String foo);
}
```

According to [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) it is possible to inject a property of spring's principal, which is not very different from what I would like to do.

Any hints on this?

Comment: `env` corresponds to the `Environment` object of Spring... So naming your property `env` is not going to work.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but as far as I know properties can be injected using @Value("${my.property}")

Comment: env is just a very badly chosen placeholder for my real implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should really stop asking questions and answer them by myself shortly after ... That is not on purpose.

The mentioned blog has the solution included. Add this:

```
public class PropertyEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {
    private final MyProps p;
    public PropertyEvaluationContextExtension(final MyProps p) {
        this.p= p;
    }
    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @Override
    public MyProps getRootObject() {
        return this.p;
    }
}
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {
    private final MyProps p;
    public PropertyConfig(final MyProps p) {
        this.p= p;
    }
    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtensionSupport propertyExtension() {
        return new PropertyEvaluationContextExtension(p);
    }
}
```

Now every property of MyProps is accessible via SpEL.

Comment: Can you please provide MyProps code and application.properties file content ?