# Update JPA Spring with parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need help for an update a tableX(Database Oracle) with external parameters,
but I don't know how.
I have an update-query in file.properties:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
            physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
            implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

chunck-limit: 10000
table-tableA:
     update-table-a: UPDATE user.tableA
     set-update-a: SET ColumnA = ?
     where-update-a: WHERE ColumnB = ?
```

Class for update with getters and setters:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ExternalConfiguration {

  @Value("${table-tableA.update-table-a}")
  private String updateTableA;

  @Value("${table-tableA.set-update-a}")
  private String setUpdateA;

  @Value("${table-tableA.where-update-a}")
  private String whereUpdateA;

  // getters + setters
}
```

Class where I need update implements ItemStreamWriter

```
public class FileItemWriterTxMonetaria implements ItemStreamWriter<TxMonetariaDTO> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileItemWriterTxMonetaria.class);



    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TxMonetariaDTO> items) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    }
}
```

How I can only update(preference) with jpa in spring?

Comment: 1. (auto)wire `EntityManager` in your `FileItemWriterTxMonetaria`. 2. use entityManager to execute (any) query (u like...within `write` method) ..getting the (query) "strings" from `ExternalConfiguration`...(alternatively to EntityManager you can use any (available) spring-data interface...whether it is possible to config (query specifics) in file ...and to generate spring-data-repositories/interfaces from it, seems also an interesting question to me.)

Comment: this sounds nice/looks good: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49817034/592355

Comment: ..alternatively to entityManger you can also wire: `DataSource`, `TransactionManager`, etc....

Comment: ..and must read: [spring-batch doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#databaseItemWriters)